# How can I replicate my mouse movements exactly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

I have been trying to figure  out how to record my mouse movements, and then replay them back with the exact same precision. For this I have attempted to use pyautogui.

My attempt to record the movement:

```
import pyautogui
import keyboard

pyautogui.MINIMUM_DURATION = 0
pyautogui.MINIMUM_SLEEP = 0
pyautogui.PAUSE = 0

mm_recording = {}
mm_recording['movement'] = []

while True:
    current_x, current_y = pyautogui.position()
    mm_recording['movement'].append((current_x, current_y))

    if keyboard.is_pressed('o'):
        break
```

My attempt to replay the movement:

```
for i in mm_recording[tuple(mm_recording.keys())[0]):
    move_x, move_y = i
    pyautogui.moveTo(move_x, move_y)
```

This does replay the trajectory the cursor was moving, but it was not exactly the same.

I tried to visualize the difference with paint:

Original:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVhKc.png

Drawn by the program:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CynJ.png

The differences are very subtle, and is mainly present in some of the curvature. What is causing these dissimilarities, and how can I fix it?

I appreciate any help!

Comment: This is a very interesting challenge!
The "simple" thing can be adding the last missing piece, I'd add another mm_recording['movement'].append((current_x, current_y)) before the break. For the slight differencies this can be a real challenge... Seems like a... Sensitivity / Rendering / Resolution problem? I am puzzled!

Comment: I would guess that the `while True` loop is recording slower than the rate that paint records mouse values

Comment: Try some of the points made in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66402166/python-win32api-cannot-draw-on-windows-paint-application

namely, use the `WM_MOUSEMOVE` event

Comment: Probably you need to also record/playback time. If it was me, I would record in seconds (as a float). Outside the loop: `start_time = time.time()`. Inside the loop: `t = start_time-time.time()`

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestions. I have no experience with the win32 modules, and am a little overwhelmed, how would this problem be formulated with the MOUSEMOVE event?

Comment: I took the time of the two loops, the recording time, and the replay time. It was indeed different, where the while loop (recording time) was always faster when the iterations was a relative big number, and the for loop was faster with fewer iterations, < 80000 different coordinates.